# jQuery .animate(), problems with toggle

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, slide

I'm relatively new to js and I'm trying to implement a simple .animate() feature in my portfolio. As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rkqge/1/), with the code I wrote the div called ribbon slides down perfectly, but it seems to ignore the "else" part of the script.

I know I'm probably doing a dumb mistake, but I can't seem to be able to work out anything better at the moment!

Sorry for my bad english, sucks to be Italian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just taking what you had, simply put the `if` inside the `click` event.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rkqge/12/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    if ($('#ribbon').css("margin-top") == "-300px") {
        $('#ribbon').animate({
            marginTop: "0px"
        }, 1700);
    } else {
        $('#ribbon').animate({
            marginTop: "-300px"
        }, 1700);
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: one thing you can add is a .stop() method before the you call animate(). `$('#ribbon').stop().animate({...`

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was doing something really stupid... it's almost midnight there, getting sleepy!

Answer (score 3):

*Just* came up with a solution for another one like this a minute ago.

http://jsfiddle.net/HF5A5/

Basically you multiply the value by 1 or -1 and then toggle that value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var direction = -1;
    $('#toggle').click(function() {
            direction -= direction * 2;
            $('#ribbon').animate({
                marginTop: "+=" + direction * 300 + "px"
            }, 1700);
            return false;
    });
});
```

or better yet: http://jsfiddle.net/HF5A5/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var direction = 1;
    $('#toggle').click(function() {
            $('#ribbon').animate({
                marginTop: "+=" + direction * 300 + "px"
            }, 1700, function(){
                $(this).stop();
                direction -= direction * 2;
            });
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Works great, but I was looking for a mistake in my code, not for a whole script :D thanks anyway!

Comment: @trascendency lol sorry about that. was fun to do, though. :)